# Refresh joined layers

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I know similar questions have been asked dozens of times, but unfortunately I tried all possible suggestions like triggerRepaint(), refresh(), refreshAllLayers() and so on, but cannot get it to work.

My problem is as follows: I have a PostGIS datasource with several points across the world. On top of that I have a country layer and based on those two, several layers created via "join attributes by location". For example to compute a sum of specific values from my points and then color the countries based on the sum.

Now when I add a new record to my PostGIS database, lets say based in a new country, after a refresh, the point is visible on my map, but the joined layers are not refreshed. So in this case the "new" country is not colored accordingly. Any idea how to do this in 2.18?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to automatically refresh the result of a geoprocessing operation when adding new data, unless you programmatically run it every time you have new values to elaborate.

Comment: Have you tried using a virtual layer?